# Visual Basic.NET - Add two numbers (I/O from file)

Tags: vb.net

Following code should sum two numbers from file "input.txt" and write the sum to "output.txt". Compilation is succesfull, but "output.txt" is still empty after running program. What am I doing wrong?

```
   Imports System.IO
    Public Class test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim scan as StreamReader = new StreamReader("input.txt")
        Dim writer as StreamWriter = new StreamWriter("output.txt", True)
        Dim input as String
        input = scan.ReadLine()
        Dim ab() as String = Split(input)
        Dim res as Integer = Val(ab(0))+Val(ab(1))
        writer.writeLine(res)
        writer.close()
    End sub
    End class
```

Comment: your code should work check if you have a permission to create file on location also try using absolute path "d:\...."

Comment: Yup.  I just tried it myself and it worked fine for me.  What's the format of the text in the input file?  Does it raise any exceptions?  Have you tried stepping through it with the debugger?

Comment: In input file there are two numbers divided by whitespace, both are located on one line.  No exceptions are thrown. I'm using an online IDE that doesn't support debugging (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_vb.net_online.php). I suppose problem is in IDE, but I don't want to install any VB.net software on my PC since this is the only program I have to write in VB in closest future. Also, when I try to submit this code to online judge, it gives runtime error.

Comment: You are probably just looking at the wrong file.  That happens when you use relative paths, always favor full paths.  Like c:\foo\bar\baz\output.txt.  Writing it to the Documents or Desktop folders would be wise, use Environment.GetFolderPath().

Comment: Could you try writing a constant string (something like "Hello") to your file, to see if the issue is in writing to the file, or if the issue is in the contents that you are trying to write?

Comment: Problem is solved. Trouble was in that online IDE, I've run code on my PC and everything worked perfectly well. Thanks @StevenDoggart for his corrections. They have no use for me since I won't write in VB.net anymore, but they may be useful for anyone who want to learn this language.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works properly for me, so as long as your input file is formatted properly (i.e. a single line with two numbers separated by spaces, like "1 2") and you have the necessary OS permissions to read and write to those files, then it should work for you too.  However, it's worth mentioning that there are several issues with your code that would be good to correct, since the fly in the face of typical best-practices.

First, you should, as much as possible, turn `Option Strict On`.  I know that you have it `Off` because your code won't compile with it `On`.  The following line is technically misleading, and therefore fails with `Option Strict On`:

```
 Dim res As Integer = Val(ab(0)) + Val(ab(1))
```

The reason if fails is because the `Val` function returns a `Double`, not an integer, so, technically, depending on the contents of the file, the result could be fractional or could be too large to fit in an `Integer`.  With `Option Strict Off`, the compiler is essentially automatically fixing your code for you, like this:

```
Dim res As Integer = CInt(Val(ab(0)) + Val(ab(1)))
```

In order to set the `res` variable equal to the result of the calculation, the more capable `Double` value must be converted down to an `Integer`.  When you are forced to put the `CInt` in the code yourself, you are fully aware that the conversion is taking place and what the consequences of it might be.  When you have `Option Strict Off` and it inserts the conversion behind-the-scenes, then you may very well miss a potential bug.

Secondly, the `Val` function is old-school VB6 syntax.  While it technically works fine, it's provided mainly for backwards compatibility.  The new .NET equivalent would be to use `Integer.Parse`, `Integer.TryParse` or `Convert.ToInt32`.

Thirdly, you never close the `scan` stream reader.  You could just add `scan.Close()` to the end of your method, but is better, when possible, to create `Using` blocks for any disposable object, like this:

```
Using scan As StreamReader = New StreamReader("test.txt")
    Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("output.txt", True)
        Dim input As String
        input = scan.ReadLine()
        Dim ab() As String = Split(input)
        Dim res As Integer = Integer.Parse(ab(0)) + Integer.Parse(ab(1))
        writer.WriteLine(res)
    End Using
End Using
```

Lastly, as Hans pointed out, it's not good to rely on the current directory.  It's always best to specify full paths for your files.  There are different methods in the framework for getting various folder paths, such as the user's desktop folder, or the download folder, or the temp folder, or the application folder, or the current application's folder, or the folder of the current running assembly.  You can use any such method to get your desired folder path, and then use `Path.Combine` to add the file name to get the full file path.  For instance:

```
Dim desktopFolderPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)
Dim inputFilePath As String = Path.Combine(desktopFolderPath, "input.txt")
Dim outputFilePath As String = Path.Combine(desktopFolderPath, "output.txt")
```